# Dynamically load java agent to IBM WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere

I'd like to load simple java agent to running java process on IBM WebSphere using `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine#attach`, then invoke loadAgent method.

With Hotspot jvm's everything works fine.

Is it possible to load java agent to IBM using `com.sun.tools.attach` package?